# Cordova ionic application won't start on device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

my case the driver is ok and the device is connected:

adb devices
List of devices attached 
7F602C136346331 device

but when i execute this command:

> ionic run android -l -c

i found this error :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/binov1/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt": error=2, No
>   >     such file or directory
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2.28 secs
>
> /home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/ElolinkProject/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error code 1 for command: /home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/ElolinkProject/platforms/android/gradlew
>   with args:
>   cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/ElolinkProject/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>   ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error:
>   /home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/ElolinkProject/platforms/android/cordova/run:
>   Command failed with exit code 8 You may not have the required
>   environment or OS to run this project

Comment: Does it work if you use the Ionic Viewer app?

Answer (score 1):

Is a problem with the build.

Install the andoid sdk
https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

verify tools and android tools is well declared in the path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/platform-tools
```

update android run command

```
> android update sdk
```

and try again.